# Does anyone know where I can find values of gravity?

Tags: gravity, earth

Does anyone know where I can find the values of gravity at different places across the globe and at different heights? I am doing an assessment on gravity and can't find any data for the values of gravity.

Comment: What kinds of values are you looking for?

Comment: Some information about the gravity of earth (according to your question's tag) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_of_Earth         and also about gravitation constant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant

Comment: Perhaps, this link (from Wolfram alpha) be the most useful: https://www.wolframalpha.com/examples/science-and-technology/physics/mechanics/kinematics/gravity/

Comment: relevant https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/grl.50838

Comment: @SG8 the main thing I'm looking for are values of gravity that have been recorded at various altitudes across the earth to see if gravity is effected by height and that it is the same everywhere on earth

Comment: @Simo12343 - the local gravity is affected by a wide variety of factors, and is decidedly not the same everywhere on earth.